# Android Getting Status on LED

Tags: android, android-widget, notifications, status, led

How can one get information on the status of items such as LED?  I know how to set LED via notifications, but what I need to know is how to determine if it is on/off etc before making any adjustments.  What I am looking for is a simple request or API that will tell me if the LED is on/off.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears this may not be available, according to this thread about the NDK (http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/10ade03e7bb7d0dc), but toward the end there is a comment that some of the leds may be available and they give the file path: `/sys/class/leds`, otherwise you may want to ask for this to be added.

If you are unfamiliar with the NDK you can look at this video series from Google Developer Day in Germany, on using the NDK to build games.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbsE-yA431c&feature=related

Comment: Well I am trying to understand the logic of being able to write a property like LED on/off and duration, and at the same time not being able to read what the property is?  This makes no sense to me.  Do you know why this would not be supported?

Comment: My guess is that they haven't seen a need for it (or they haven't needed it), as you can just tell it to turn on, and if it is on, I would assume it does nothing, but, is there a need to know the state before sending a command to turn it on/off?