# How can Arduino detect the state of an LED?

Tags: arduino, led

I'm working on a blinking/fading lights program for Arduino. I'm trying to build in some interactivity that's based on LED state and certain switch combinations. Consider: When a button is pressed, if an LED is ON I want to turn it off and if an LED is OFF I want to turn it on.

However, I've not been able to find any information about determining LED state. The closest was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788529/android-getting-status-on-led) about Android, but I'm trying to find out if I can do this from the Arduino platform. Does anyone have any practical experience or advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options:

One, you can store the LED state in a boolean, and on button press, negate that and write it to the LED port:

```
void loop()
{
    static int ledState = 0; // off
    while (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN) == 0)
        ; // wait for button press

    ledState = !ledState;
    digitalWrite(LED_PORT, ledState);
}
```

Two, if you don't mind accessing the ports of the AVR directly:

```
void init()
{
    DDRD = 0x01; // for example: LED on port B pin 0, button on port B pin 1
    PORTB = 0x00;
}

void loop()
{
    while (PINB & 0x02 == 0)
        ; // loop until the button is pressed

    PORTB ^= 0x01; // flip the bit where the LED is connected
}
```

Comment: direct access to the AVR ports is more desirable. Questions about the code, though--still a coding newbie. :) DDRD & PORTB...are those Arduino constants? arbitrary variable names? Does the hex value just represent the pin number? e.g., LED on pin 8 would be expressed as `PORTB = 0x08`? And how do I determine if a pin is on "port B" or not? Thanks!

Comment: @dwwilson66 These are constants declared in `<avr/io.h>`. The hex value represents the pin number as a bitmask, i. e. pin X is `1 << x`, so pin 8 (well, it's rather pin 7) is `1 << 7 = 128 = 0x80`. Determining which pin is on which port? AVR datasheet.

Comment: Hardware constants...got it. I'll be studying the datasheet more in depth later today! Thanks so much for helping me understand it!

Comment: A bit of a side note: In regard to using bit values directly or saving a Boolean, I'd use a Boolean. You maybe writing for one device, but with so many different Arduino platforms out there you wont be able to port your code. Booleans are more indirect, but allow you to separate yourself from the code. --Just a thought

Answer (score 5):

It is absolutely OK to read output ports. That is

```
digitalWrite(LED_PORT, !digitalRead(LED_PORT));
```

will toggle the pin.

You might also want to consider the toggle library: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/DigitalToggle

Comment: Thanks! Simple and elegant. I'll be perusing the toggle library later. Avesome avatar. :)