# Check the mode of a pin

Tags: arduino

There is anyway to check the mode of a pin ?
like digitalRead(somePin) returns high or low
so some function the returns input or output

Im using arduino mega 2560...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can Arduino detect the state of an LED?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138176/how-can-arduino-detect-the-state-of-an-led)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Arduino library doesn't provide a function to read the mode of a pin. It is possible to read a mode however, and if you like you can review this documentation:[Atmel-2549](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf)
Reading a pin state will involve you having to figure out a port and register to read your mode from. This isn't recommended because the pin and port configuration will likely change between versions of micro-controllers. If you try to do something invalid to your hardware through your program you could end up with a fried microchip.
It would probably be best to store the mode as a variable to check what mode the pin in question has been set to.